# Amazon: get product inventory location (country) using the SKU

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm working on a web app that uses the Amazon MWS API and I was able to get a list of all products from a particular seller using the Reports API, report type being set to "_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_". I get the "seller_sku" for each product, but now I would like to know where product is located using the SKU since in Europe there are about 7 Amazon warehouses (UK, France, Germany, Italy, Spain, Czech Republic and Poland).

I couldn't find anything in the Amazon MWS docs about this. Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could user these marketplace ID to map your SKU/s to find the Warehouse location More details [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html):

```
US/Canada
CA  A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2
MX  A1AM78C64UM0Y8
US  ATVPDKIKX0DER

Europe:
DE  A1PA6795UKMFR9
ES  A1RKKUPIHCS9HS
FR  A13V1IB3VIYZZH
IT  APJ6JRA9NG5V4
UK  A1F83G8C2ARO7P

India:
IN  A21TJRUUN4KGV

Japan:
JP  A1VC38T7YXB528

China:
CN  AAHKV2X7AFYLW
```

Answer (score 0):

*From an edit to the question, moved to an answer post*:

I sent a message to amazon and they said this is not possible, thanks for your time.